# Counting dates (as a class) in R

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a simple data frame in R, as follows:

```
#example data frame
a = c("red","red","green")
b = c("01/01/1900","01/02/1950","01/05/1990")
df = data.frame(a,b)
colnames(df)<-c("Color","Dates")
```

My goal is to count the number of dates (as a class - not individually) for each variable in the "Color" column. So, the result would look like this:

```
#output should look like this:
a = c("red","green")
b = c("2","1")
df = data.frame(a,b)
colnames(df)<-c("Color","Dates")
```

Red was associated with two dates -- the dates themselves are unimportant, I'd just like to count the aggregate number of dates per color in the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Dates = uniqueN(Dates)) , Color]
#   Color Dates
#1:   red     2
#2: green     1
```

Comment: This would work, but what if the dates are not unique? So, in red for example, both dates are "01/01/1900" ?

Comment: @knaslund  It will be 1 using this answer.  What is your expected for that case?  Do you need `setDT(df)[, .(Dates = .N), Color]`

Comment: ah, yes this seems like it will work fabulously! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Or in base R:

```
sapply(split(df, df$Color), nrow)
# green   red 
#     1     2
```

Comment: I like this one best.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. A complication, however - let's say there is an NA in red, like this: `a=c("red","red","red","green")`
`b=c("01/01/1900","01/02/1950","NA","01/05/1990")`
`df=data.frame(a,b)`
`colnames(df)<-c("Color","Dates")` ...could we not count the NA somehow?

Comment: You could just start by omitting `NA` values: `df <- omit.na(df)` and then continue as before. It just occurred to me that you can simply use `table(df$Color)` to get what you want if you are really just counting the number of times each color occurs in the table (after removing `NA` values).

Answer (score 0):

using the `dplyr` package from the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Color) %>% summarise(n())
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#    Color `n()`
#   <fctr> <int>
# 1  green     1
# 2    red     2
```